# Implement SQL Union Query using Query Builder in Doctrine Symfony2

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I'm currently using Symfony2 framework. I don't know how to join 2 of my query by Query Builder in Symfony2, I just can join them using SQL UNION query. Below is the query that returns correct results.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT m.id, m.subject, m.date 
FROM message m JOIN message_incoming mi ON m.id = mi.id
WHERE m.recipient_id = 1
AND mi.trash = 1
AND mi.deleted = 0) AS y
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT m.id, m.subject, m.date 
FROM message m JOIN message_outgoing mo ON m.id = mo.id
WHERE m.originator_id = 1
AND mo.trash = 1
AND mo.sent = 1
AND mo.deleted = 0) AS z
ORDER BY date DESC
```

I was trying to join this code in just 1 query (without UNION) to get the correct result but I failed.

So how can I implement this query using query builder?

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: @BorisGuéry The query above runs on phpmyadmin just fine without errors. But the problem is I need to implement it using Query Builder.

Comment: What did you try? And what was the error that makes you think it failed? Or maybe you're looking for someone who can write the query for you?

Comment: SELECT m.id, m.subject, m.date
FROM message m 
JOIN message_incoming mi ON m.id = mi.id
JOIN message_outgoing mo ON m.id = mo.id
WHERE m.recipient_id = 1
AND mi .trash = 1
AND mi .deleted = 0
OR mo .trash = 1
AND mo .deleted =0
AND mo .sent = 1
ORDER by date DESC

this was what I tried to avoid UNION but it returns null which is not correct, and Yes, I'm currently looking for someone who can join the query (avoid UNION) or can implement the UNION by query builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how stupid I am when joining 2 queries without checking the conditions.
This is the correct query :

```
SELECT m.id, m.subject, m.date
FROM message m 
JOIN message_incoming mi ON m.id = mi.id
JOIN message_outgoing mo ON m.id = mo.id
WHERE m.recipient_id = 1
AND mi .trash = 1
AND mi .deleted = 0
OR m.originator_id = 1
AND mo .trash = 1
AND mo .deleted =0
AND mo .sent = 1
ORDER by date DESC
```

I tried implement it through query builder :

```
$queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->getRepository('EzxWebmailBundle:Message')
            ->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->select('m.id','m.subject','m.date')
            ->join('m.message_outgoing','mo','ON','m.id = mo.id')
            ->join('m.message_incoming','mi','ON','m.id = mi.id')
            ->where('m.recipient_id = '.$userId)
            ->andWhere('mi.trash = 1')
            ->andWhere('mi.deleted = 0')
            ->orWhere('m.originator_id = '.$userId)
            ->andWhere('mo.trash = 1')
            ->andWhere('mo.deleted = 0')
            ->andWhere('mo.sent = 1')
            ->orderBy('m.date','DESC');
$result = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

How surprisingly it returns incorrect result ! So i tried to see what query was generated using :

```
var_dump($queryBuilder->getQuery());
```

And I really don't know why doctrine generates extra parenthesis as I get this result (carefully have a look at WHERE clause) :

```
SELECT m.id, m.subject, m.date FROM message m 
INNER JOIN message_outgoing mo ON m.id = mo.id
INNER JOIN message_incoming mi ON m.id = mi.id
WHERE ((m.recipient_id = 1 AND mi.trash = 1 AND mi.deleted = 0) OR m.originator_id = 1) AND mo.trash = 1 AND mo.deleted = 0 AND mo.sent = 1 
ORDER BY m.date DESC
```

So this must be the correct one if I add my own parenthsis :

```
$queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->getRepository('EzxWebmailBundle:Message')
            ->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->select('m.id','m.subject','m.date')
            ->join('m.message_outgoing','mo','ON','m.id = mo.id')
            ->join('m.message_incoming','mi','ON','m.id = mi.id')
            ->where('(m.recipient_id = '.$userId)
            ->andWhere('mi.trash = 1')
            ->andWhere('mi.deleted = 0)')
            ->orWhere('(m.originator_id = '.$userId)
            ->andWhere('mo.trash = 1')
            ->andWhere('mo.deleted = 0')
            ->andWhere('mo.sent = 1)')
            ->orderBy('m.date','DESC')
```

Feel a little stupid.

Comment: dude you should use parameters when working with variables in query builder. dont just concatenate the string with your variable

Answer (score 2):

The best way to write such query without making to much hack on Doctrine2 itself would be to use [`NativeQuery`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html).

The native/sql `QueryBuilder` uses the exactly same API as the ORM. And you are able to map result to an existing entity.